# Memory gradually increasing until crash while training simple MLP on CPU with Theano

Tags: python, memory, machine-learning, theano

I am running this [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/mlp.html) that is training a simple MLP on MNIST. I run on CPU. While monitoring my computer activity in the training loop, I can see that the memory usage is steadily increasing, until it reaches 100% and everything crashes (need to reboot). I was experiencing this problem with my own script and thought I made a mistake, but when I experienced the same issue on the tutorial above, I started suspecting a bug in Theano and also opened an [issue](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5810) on github.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and using the bleeding edge version of Theano.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue on CPU?
Does anyone have a clue about which op might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work-around has been proposed to my corresponding [post](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5810) on theano-issues on github. I am spreading the answer here.

Apparently, the issue come from a bug in Theano 0.9.0. As this leak will need to be fixed by the developers, a simple work-around is to revert to Theano 0.8.2. It can be easily done like this :

```
pip install theano==0.8.2
```

Theano 0.9.0 should be automatically uninstalled and replaced by the older version.

Result : same code, no more memory leak!

Comment: I was experiencing similar symptoms on Windows with Theano 0.9.0 and this fixed it for me. If you are using Anaconda you can downgrade to 0.8.2 using:

    conda install theano=0.8.2